# Mysql using LIKE to match phone number

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an app where user phone book uploaded on server same like whatsapp,telegram,facebook etc.

User imported phone book structure look like this

Table Name: PhoneBook

```
id  user_id first_name   mobile(Varchar(20))               
1   100      John        +91981000000
2   100      Tom         91981000001
3   100      Ron         9810-000-02
4   100      Mat         91981000003
5   100      Miley       981000004
```

Table Name: Registered_User (Main Table For Existing Users)

```
ID  Name   Phone (Varchar(20))           
1   Sam  09811111111
2   Abby 919811000000
3   Ben  +19854646464
4   Tom  +91981000001
5   Ron  981000002
6   Sam  981111145
```

So When user wants to see how many friends of my existing contact on the app then first i need to grab all contacts of user with his/her user_id (100 in above example) from PhoneBook table then i need to check if anyone from user_id = 100 phonebook's exist on Table Registered_User and if yes then returns all of Registered_User table column

Here is my query

```
SELECT * FROM Registered_User as MA 
  Join PhoneBook as N ON N.mobile Like '%' MA.Phone 
where N.user_id = 100
```

Table Schema

```
CREATE TABLE `Phonebook` (
 `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` int NOT NULL,
 `first_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
 `mobile` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3520 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The query above returns zero result even when the user 100(user id) has few users in Registered_User table. Can you help me to fix this query. I am not expert in creating query.

Table data should return result Tom 981000001 and Ron 981000002. Please let me know if i missed something and is this the best way to get the get the existing users of the app?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html

Comment: @is anything wrong with my query?

Comment: If you are going to use the phone number as an important part of finding people from your DB I suggest to make sure the phone numbers are entered all in the same format

Comment: @RiggsFolly It's not possible because phonebook coming from user devices and it's ok for us to use like than exact match. Any idea how we can match phone numbers with like so we can skip country code or zeros etc

Comment: `N.mobile Like CONCAT('%', MA.Phone)`

Comment: @RiggsFolly is right, you need to make sure that the phone numbers are stored in a consistent format. I understand that the raw data comes from the users' devices, however, you can reformat the data during the import process. Matching the data on the fly will be very slow and prone to errors.

Comment: Please read [this](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber/blob/master/FALSEHOODS.md). Handling phone numbers is a notorious pain in the axx neck. `N.mobile LIKE CONCAT('%', MA.phone, '%')` may help but it's about the slowest SQL filter in the world.

Comment: @M.Eriksson Now i am cleaning each and every number before inserting in database as you suggested in my deleted question. Like removing spaces and dashes. Filter out country code and phone number is not possible like i see few number like this `+910119810012345` it's same number and valid too. so getting perfect number might create issue when getting result back